# Fetching all .ch files from FTP into website

Tags: php, fetch

I need to fetch all the .ch files (located inside a specific folder) from my FTP server into my website using PHP. May I receive some guidance about how can I do it?

Comment: FTP and HTTP are on the same server or on a different server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading these [basic examples](http://php.net/manual/en/ftp.examples-basic.php) from the PHP manual, you can use parts of this code:

```
<?php 
$dir = "/ftpdir/source/"; 
$dir1= "/websitedir/newfolder/" 

// Open a directory, and read its contents 
if (is_dir($dir)){ 
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){ 
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){ 
      //Check the file extension, several methods available 
      $ext=pathinfo($dir.$file); 
      // If the extension is ch, then copy the file 
      if($ext == "ch") { 
             if(copy($dir.$file,$dir1.$file)) { 
                      echo $dir.$file." has been copied to ".$dir1.$file."<br>"; 
                } 
             else { echo "Something went wrong.<br>"; } 
            } 
    } 
    closedir($dh); 
  } 
} 
?>
```

I hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php

Example:

```
<?php

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// get contents of the current directory
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");

// output $contents
var_dump($contents);

?>
```

You can easy apply this for .ch using `if($something == "ch") {...}`